# Node/Express/Formidable multipart form - request body is *absent* on server

Tags: node.js, express, fetch, multipartform-data, formidable

I am new to Node/Express (but not to development).. It was all going swimmingly - but I have hit a real roadblock.

I am trying to get a framework in place for an 'SPA' HTML game.

I'm trying to POST multipart/form-data  - as eventually I will want to do file uploads.

I'm using Fetch and the FormData object for POSTS - as I want to 'Ajax' HTML fragments/JSON into my SPA

My POST *looks* ok (to me) client-side -
[Post data headers/payload/client-side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Moemv.png)

The have a multipart payload

but the request body is entirely absent server-side (which (presumably) causes Formidable to return an empty set of fields)

[No request.body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T72M6.png)

```
 const form = formidable({ multiples: true });

let outFields={}
form.parse(cmd.request,(err,fields,files)=>{outFields=fields})
```

I swear at one point - the request had a body property, but it was an empty object{} which isn't very useful either

**Things I have tried:-**

- List item

Faffed about with CORS

```
//CORS - without this we cannot accept multipart forms (or do several other things later - this really wants locking down before production)
app.use((req, res, next:Function) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET'); // Add other methods here
  next();
});
```

- List item

Put in, Taken, out (and shaken all about) the middleware:--

```
app.use(logger('dev'));
//app.use(express.json());
//app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
//app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

(maybe that where the empty body came in)

- List item

'Funded' and reached out for paid support at https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable  (no reply yet)

- List item

Messed with the form (added an enctype and method attribute) - to no avail

- List item

Pulled quite a lot of my own hair out

- Stepped a fair way into the library - but TBH this is beyond my expertise

So to Boil it down:-

here's my form:-

```
<form id='signIn' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <p>Enter your player name <input type='text' name='pName'></p>
      <p>Enter your password <input type='password' name='password'></p>
    </form>
    
    <!--(method, url,elementId,mode,formDataObj){ -->
    <button onclick="ajax('POST','signIn','main','i',new FormData($('#signIn')[0]))">Sign In</button>
    </form>
```

Here's the ajax helper method (not very pretty yet - sorry):-

```
//Fetch is the modern, native way - it is well described here https://javascript.info/fetch
  function ajax(method, url,elementId,mode,formDataObj){
    //we return a promise so we can await (completion if we want to)        
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{resolve(fetch(url, {method:method,body:formDataObj,headers:{'Accept':'text/html','Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'}}).then(response=>fillElement(elementId,response,mode)))}) //response is a promise 
  }
```

and (not that it's very relevant) - here is the router/"controller" code

```
router.get('/*', (req:e.Request, res:e.Response, next:e.NextFunction)=> {processRequest(req,res,next)}) //res.render("main",{player:} }) //

function processRequest(req:e.Request,res:e.Response,next:e.NextFunction){
  
  //siginIn,signUp,signOut


  const action=req.path.split('/')[1]  //we're going to see if the controller object has a function matching the (first segment of) the path - NB: path[0] is what before the first slash (i.e. - nothing)
     
  if(controller.hasOwnProperty(action)){  //see if the controller object has a function matching the (first segment of) the path 
    const game:Game=global["game"] //get a type safe reference to the game
    let player:Player = game.playerFromCookie(req.cookies.pid)
    
    console.log (req.path)

    //construct a parameters object to pass useful info into the controller[action] method
    //export interface Params {readonly game:Game,readonly player:Player,request:e.Request,response:e.Response}
    let params:controller.Params = {game:game, player:player, request:req , response:res}
    //Invoke the method (action) with tha handy parameters
    let output:{template:string,data:any} = controller[action](params)

    res.render(output.template, {player:output.data})
```

Thanks in advance for your time

Answer (score 0):

Your form has 2  `</form>` which makes 2 forms.

Also

```
let outFields={}
form.parse(cmd.request,(err,fields,files)=>{outFields=fields})
```

is not going to do what it looks like. I recommend you to learn more about how callbacks work in general, and when you do it will be obvious why this code is sloppy.

And your ajax code also shows you have no clue about Promise , so read the docs and gl hf